# Scalar curvature of homogeneous bounded domains

Tags: kahler-manifolds, curvature, homogeneous-spaces

Is it true that a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb C^n$ equipped with a homogeneous metric (not necessarily a Bergman metric) has (constant) negative scalar curvature?